# jQuery Animate Method -- duration isn't working

Tags: jquery, scroll, duration

I have a jQuery scroll set up, but the duration is not working properly.
On a the "About Page" of a Wordpress site, I want to use jQuery so that upon click of a photo, it scrolls down to the appropriate div. The scroll is working, however, the duration is not. The scroll takes about 1/4 a second and it doesn't matter at what speed I set the duration. The site I'm referring can be seen at: http://teamcoding.ca/corporate/about-test/

Below is the source code for the jQuery scroll.

```
$(function(){
    $('a[href*=.staff_photos_indiv]').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,") == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,") && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var $target = $target;
            $target = $(this.hash);
            $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if ($target.length) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, {easing:'easeInOutExpo',duration:1600});
                return false;
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: For someone stumbling upon this ilke me: Make sure duration is a number and not a string, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that you don't have the `'easeInOutExpo'` easing function defined because the general operation works with this code:

```
$(document.body).animate(
    {scrollTop: "400px"}, {easing: "swing", duration: 1600}
);
```

And, you can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/UbnUh/

Comment: Hmm yeah that code works for me as well. I think the issue is the 'targetOffset', but I'm not sure of an alternative to get to the particular divs.

Comment: @mcranston18 - to you need to add "px" units to the targetOffset?

Comment: @mcranston18 - you'd add units right when you pass it to animate.  jQuery may assume "px" units if you don't have them there (I'm not sure), but the underlying CSS needs units on all dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in jQuery selector.

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href*=.staff_photos_indiv]`

That's why `click` event is not even firing.
What you see is just `a href="#...` acting in normal way.

Answer (score 0):

The way to debug this is to open the page in chrome, right click and select "Inspect Element" the last menu choice.

Choose the last tab on the right, console, and you'll see if any errors exist in JavaScript:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href*=.staff_photos_indiv]
```

Instead, try a simpler selector:

```
$('.staff_photos_indiv').click( ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer hagope. I've made the change to my code but this still has not changed the fact that duration still isn't working properly in my code?